# I can not edit in the code behind anything that is between the itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms, itemtemplate

I need to access in the code behind some labels that are inside an ITEMTEMPLATE, I can not even apply RUNAT = SERVER and put an ID !! in fact, nothing that is inside the ITEMTEMPLATE I can access in the code behind! I need the listview + item template PRA to display some information from my database, but I also need to add and manipulate some labels, how should I do this?

MY CODE :

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <asp:ListView ID="lv_post" runat="server">

                    <ItemTemplate runat="server">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h2 class="titulo"><b><%# Eval("titulo")%></b></h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="data" style="margin-bottom: 1px;"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i><%# Eval("data") %> <i class="fas fa-user"></i><%# Eval("autor") %></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela1" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela2" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela3" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela4" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela5" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <p class="conteudo">"<%# Eval("conteudo") %>"</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <%--<%# Eval("id_categoria_fk") %>--%>
                        <hr />

                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:ListView>

            </div>
        </div>
```

i can't acess this on code behind:

```
                                <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela1" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela2" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela3" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela4" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela5" CssClass="fa fa-star" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            </div>
```

if I move out of ITEMTEMPLATE I can, but I need this information in the middle of information that only appears in the itemtemplate.

Comment: You need to access the items by the ItemTemplate Index because there can be more than one control: `var lbl = lv_post.FindControl("lbl_estrela1") as Label;`

Comment: i can for exemple change the style of a label using this ? how?
For what I saw you are getting the value of the label and putting it in the var, but I had to manipulate the attributes of the label!

Comment: You can, `lbl` is typeof Label. so it has all the properties.

Comment: i use var lbl1 = lv_post.FindControl("lbl_estrela1") as Label;
so i try lbl1.Attributes.Add("style", "color: #d40000;"); and give me exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` contains **a list** of items. The `ItemTemplate` describes the layout of **each one** of these items. So, the `Label` controls inside the template exist **for every item** of the list.

Here is a working example:

**ASPX Page**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .color2 {
            color: #d40000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ListView ID="lv_post" runat="server" ItemType="String">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_estrela" runat="server" Text="<%# Item %>"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public string[] data = { "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", "Data 4" };

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lv_post.DataSource = data;
        lv_post.DataBind();

        var lbl_estrela1 = lv_post.Items[1].FindControl("lbl_estrela") as Label;
        lbl_estrela1.CssClass = "color2";

        var lbl_estrela3 = lv_post.Items[3].FindControl("lbl_estrela") as Label;
        lbl_estrela3.CssClass = "color2";
    }
}
```

In the above example, the css style of the second and the fourth label is set to `color2`. Note, the use of the `Items` collection.

**Optional**

To better understand, take a look at the page source generated when the page is loaded.

```
<div>            
    <span id="lv_post_lbl_estrela_0">Data 1</span>
    <br />

    <span id="lv_post_lbl_estrela_1" class="color2">Data 2</span>
    <br />

    <span id="lv_post_lbl_estrela_2">Data 3</span>
    <br />

    <span id="lv_post_lbl_estrela_3" class="color2">Data 4</span>
    <br />                
</div>
```